# Closest point on the surface of an ellipsoid to a given point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry, quadrics

Given the ellipsoid

$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0) = 1$

And a point $A$ anywhere in space, I want to find the closest point $r^*$ on the ellipsoid to $A$.

**My attempt:**

Define the scalar function:

$F(r) = (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0) - 1 $

The gradient of this function at any point $r$ is

$ \nabla F = 2 Q (r - r_0) $

The above gradient vector is perpendicular to the surface of the ellipsoid at point $r$.

Therefore, the closest point $r^*$ on the ellipsoid to point $A$ satisfies

$ (r^* - A) =  K Q (r^* - r_0) $

For some constant $K$.

Solving these equations is discussed in my solution below.

Comments, and hints, and **alternative solutions**, are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to solve the optimization problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|r-A\|^2 \to \min! \qquad
\text{s.t.}\qquad (r-r_0)^T Q (r-r_0) = 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
The KKT conditions for this problem amount to
$$
\begin{aligned}
r-A = KQ(r-r_0), \qquad (r-r_0)^T Q (r-r_0) = 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
precisely as you write, where I denoted the Lagrange multiplier associated with the equality constraint by $K$ to be consistent with your notation.
Since $Q$ is symmetric and positive definite (as you have an ellipsoid) it admits a spectral decomposition $V\Lambda V^T$, where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors of $Q$, and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of $Q$'s eigenvalues (which are positive).  Let us substitute this into the first KKT condition:
$$
r-A = K V\Lambda V^T (r-r_0).
$$
Let us denote the coordinates of $r-r_0$ in the basis of $V$ by $x$, and of $A-r_0$ by $y$, i.e.
$$
r-r_0 = VV^T(r-r_0) =: Vx, \qquad 
A-r_0 = VV^T(A-r_0) =: Vy.
$$
We can reshuffle our KKT condition a little:
$$
(r-r_0)-(A-r_0) = K V\Lambda V^T (r-r_0),
$$
or
$$
Vx - KV\Lambda x = Vy,
$$
or
$$
(I-K\Lambda)x = y,
$$
or, component-wise, assuming $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_i)$
$$
(1-K\lambda_i)x_i = y_i.
$$
In particular, if $y_i = 0$ we can e.g. set $K=\lambda_i^{-1}$ and get the equality regardless of $x_i$.  If, on the other hand, $y_i \neq 0$ then we cannot put $K=\lambda_i^{-1}$.
Thus we obtain the following candidate solutions for $x$, from which $r=r_0+Vx$ is determined.

**Case 1.** Assuming $K\neq \lambda_i^{-1}$, we get $x_i = [1-K\lambda_i]^{-1}y_i$, and ultimately to a the following scalar equation for $K$ from the second KKT condition:
$$
\sum_{i} \frac{\lambda_i}{[1-K\lambda_i]^2}y_i^2 = 1.
$$
Note that this equation is unsolvable, when $y=0$.

**Case 2.** Assume that $\lambda_i = \hat{\lambda}$ for $i\in \hat{I}$, and $y_i = 0$ for all $i\in \hat{I}$. Then then we can set $K=\hat{\lambda}^{-1}$.  In this case, we compute other $x$-coordinates as before, i.e., $x_i = [1-K\lambda_i]^{-1}y_i = [1-\hat{\lambda}^{-1}\lambda_i]^{-1}y_i$ for $i\not\in \hat{I}$, while $x_i$ for $i\in \hat{I}$ are undertermined from the first KKT condition.  We end up with the equation:
$$
\sum_{i\in \hat{I}} \hat{\lambda} x_i^2 + 
\sum_{i\not\in \hat{I}} \frac{\lambda_i}{[1-\hat{\lambda}^{-1}\lambda_i]^2}y_i^2 = 1,
$$
which, when solvable, gives us at least two, or when multiplicity of $\hat{\lambda}$ is more then one, infinitely many candidate solutions $x_i$, $i\in \hat{I}$.

**Example 1:**
Assume we work in dimension $2$, $\Lambda = \text{diag}[1,2]$, $V=I$, $r_0 = [0,0]$, $A=[1/2,1/4]$. In this example $y=A$, where none of its components are $0$.  Thus we arrive at the following equation for $K$:
$$\frac{1}{4[1-K]^2}+\frac{2}{16[1-2K]^2} = 1.$$
This equation happens to have two solutions, $K_1\approx 0.260161052873378$ and $K_2\approx 1.50787304726301$, see desmos plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2epqywc5nf).  This gives us two KKT points: $x_1 \approx [0.73166349, 0.681666]$ and $x_2 \approx [-0.984498, -0.12402356]$.  The situation is described in [this desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m10fha8dhw).

**Example 2:**
Assume we work in dimension $2$, $\Lambda = \text{diag}[1,2]$, $V=I$, $r_0 = [0,0]$, $A=[1/2,0]$. In this example $y=A$, where $y_2 = 0$.
In case 1 we have the the following equation for $K$:
$$\frac{1}{4[1-K]^2} = 1.$$
This equation happens to have two solutions, $K_1=1.5$ and $K_2=0.5$, see desmos plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lqhykdp0nt).  Note that $K_2 = \lambda_2^{-1}$, so we will not use it for case 1.  Thus case 1 results in 1 KKT point: $x_1 =[-1,0]$.

For case 2 we put $K_2 = \lambda_2^{-1} = 0.5$.  We compute $x_{2,1} = y_1/[1-K_2\lambda_1] = 1.0$, and $x_{2,2}$ from the equation $\lambda_1 x_{2,1}^2 + \lambda_2 x_{2,2}^2 = 1$.  This gives us a double root $x_{2,2}=0.0$, shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ivvb1eqyfv).

**Example 3:**
Assume we work in dimension $2$, $\Lambda = \text{diag}[1,2]$, $V=I$, $r_0 = [0,0]$, $A=[1/3,0]$. In this example $y=A$, where $y_2 = 0$.
In case 1 we have the the following equation for $K$:
$$\frac{1}{9[1-K]^2} = 1.$$
This equation happens to have two solutions, $K_1=2/3$ and $K_2=4/3$, see desmos plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fbzww9mweq). Thus case 1 results in 2 KKT point: $x_1 =[1,0]$ and $x_2 = [-1,0]$.

For case 2 we put $K_2 = \lambda_2^{-1} = 0.5$.  We compute $x_{3,1} =x_{4,1} = y_1/[1-K_2\lambda_1] = 2/3$.  We then compute $x_{3,2}$ and $x_{4,2}$ from the equation $\lambda_1 x_{3,1}^2 + \lambda_2 x_{3,2}^2 = 1$.  This gives us two roots $x_{3,2}=\sqrt{[1-4/9]/2}\approx 0.5270462766947299$, and $x_{4,2}\approx -0.5270462766947299$ shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hos8ozedkn).  So in this case we have 4 KKT points.

I hope this illustrates the computations.

Thanks @Chris Lewis.

Comment: Great solution! Presumably the interpretation for the second root of the quadratic in $K$ is the point that maximises $||r-A||^2$. Out of interest, what does this mean for points *inside* the ellipsoid? I can think of a few cases where we would expect multiple solutions. The most simple is when two of the ellipsoid's semiaxes are the same; points along the axis of symmetry would have a solution set in the shape of a circle. In general, wouldn't we also expect problems to arise when the point $A$ is on two normals to the ellipsoid?

Comment: Of course you are right, one should be more careful with inverting the matrix.  If we are at the center of the circle, e.g., then $y=0$ and the thing with inversion falls apart as we would need to set $K=\lambda$.  I will try to edit this if I have time.

Comment: Working in dimension $2$ is not the problem here, it is working in dimension $3$.  Can you add an example, where you're working with a 3D ellipsoid ?

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  I've verified your results against my own, and found that they match.

Answer (score 0):

The equation

$ (r^* - A) = K Q (r^* - r_0) $

This equation can be replaced with a vector cross product equation:

$ (r^* - A) \times Q (r^* - r_0) = \mathbf{0} $

If $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are the standard basis unit vectors, then define

$ C_1= e_2 e_3^T - e_3 e_2^T $

$ C_2 = e_3 e_1^T - e_1 e_3^T $

$ C_3 = e_1 e_2^T - e_2 e_1^T $

Then the vector cross product equation equation can be written as the following three equations:

$(r^* - A)^T C_1 Q (r^* - r_0) = 0 $

$(r^* - A)^T C_2 Q (r^* - r_0) = 0 $

$(r^* - A)^T C_3 Q (r^* - r_0) = 0 $

Choosing two of these equations (for example, the first two), combined with the equation of the ellipse gives us a system of quadratic equations in $3$ unknowns which are the coordinates of $r^*$.  Solving these equations gives multiple solutions which be check against the third equation from the last set (involving $C_3$) to verify it is satisfied.

And then choosing the minimum possible distance $\| r^* - A \|$ gives the required $r^*$.